# Filemaker: How to fetch list of related entities

Tags: filemaker

I'm new to Filemaker, but have extensive SQL experience.

How do I add a list of children to my Filemaker layout, if I have a one-to-many relationship (a tree)? I would like to see for my current node all its children. Later I want to filter them as well.

Showing the parent is easy via the related field. But for the reverse it appears that I need to use scripts?

In SQL, I would write:

```
SELECT * from Element WHERE parent = {current_id};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up a relationship between the tables in the relationship graph using a primary key and foreign key arrangement. Then you add a portal to the related table occurrence on your main table layout. You can add filtering in the relationship itself or in the portal afterwards.

I advice you to check out [this](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5561/~/working-with-portals---displaying-related-data) info from FileMaker on the subject.

Comment: I manage to show **parents** this way, but not **children**. The table is self-referencing as parent => ID.

Comment: Ok, then you need to set up another table occurrence to the main table and use a self join predicate. Then add a portal to this new table occurrence.

Comment: That was what I was missing. So to use relationships bi-directional, you actually need to set up two relationships. That was unexpected, now it works.

Comment: Not as such, FileMaker's relationships are always bidirectional, but it all comes down to context. The layout context, any calculation field's context, etc. Glad you got it working.

Comment: So is this due to the way I set up the relationship? Is there a way to set up **one** relationship and have it available both ways?

Comment: In principle, in its simplest form, you'll have at least one layout for each table occurrence. You can relate all table occurrence to each other in a "spider" configuration, where all table occurrences are available through portals from any other layout, bidirectionally. Though in larger systems, this is not a recommended configuration. We almost always use one-directional relationships for clarity and logic reasons. I would need to see your graph to advice you further on this.